# Convert Java to JavaScript that runs on JVM

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, rhino, nashorn

I'm a huge fan of GWT (converts Java into JavaScript that runs in a browser), but are there any tools out there that convert Java to JavaScript to be run in the JVM (via Nashorn or Rhino)?

**Update**

More information... the idea I'm exploring is to compile back-end code to JavaScript, then store it in a database. Web apps could then pull a back-end "module" out of the database and execute it on the server.

**Update**

I'm not posting this as an answer, because I'm doubting it's a good idea, but out of curiousity I tried running GWT-generated JavaScript in the JVM. Compiling at "detailed" level I had to mock 3 DOM objects that GWT expects to exist (hack!), but it does work.

Test.gwt.xml

```
<module rename-to='test'>
  <entry-point class='test.client.Test'/>
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>
  <super-source path="jre"></super-source>
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>
```

...note the super-source jre...

test/client/Test.java

```
public class Test implements EntryPoint {
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    print("" + new File("/Users/.../someFile.txt").exists());
    print("Hey");
  }

  public native void print(String msg) /*-{
    print(msg);
  }-*/;
}
```

...the mocked File class...

test/jre/java/io/File.java

```
public class File {

  public File(String name) {
    _init(name);
  }

  private native void _init(String name) /*-{
    this._obj = new java.io.File(name);
  }-*/;

  public native boolean exists() /*-{
    return this._obj.exists();
  }-*/;
}
```

test/RhinoTest.java

```
public class RhinoTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ScriptException {
    String js = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/Users/.../Test/war/test/130CD4F977EDEB096DFEF9871580F1CD.cache.js"));
    js = "var $wnd = { test: { __sendStats: function() {} } };"
       + js;
    new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval(js);
  }
}
```

Produces:

```
trueHey
```

Comment: Rhino compiles  js to class, you could Provide an Applet runtime (for security) and run the compiled Java code  directly.

Comment: I just updated my question with more information about my use-case. I need to run the this on a server, not in a browser. Unless you know something I don't, it's not any easier to run an applet in a server than to dynamically load a jar and run it.

Comment: Why don't you just write JavaScript?

Comment: We're an all Java shop. We have large apps and the organization has purposely chosen Java because of the structure that static typing provides. I'm considering an alternate deployment strategy for our existing apps. If I were to suggest that we rewrite all our apps in JavaScript, that conversation would not go well =).

Comment: Have you had a look at osgi stacks? Like equinox or apache felix? Otherwise I think the idea to use gwt that way seems to work for you - you should possibly answer the question, or rephrase it, as I see no question to be answered anymore :-)

Comment: @thst My original question was "is there a tool out there for this" and my guess is that, at the moment, there isn't (from lack of answers), but I don't think my update qualifies as an answer since it's a hack against a tool meant for something else, not a tool meant for this job. Unless there's a problem with me doing so, I'll leave the question open so that in the future if something is developed, I'll get an answer.

Comment: There is an old project http://j2s.sourceforge.net/overview.html that provides a java 2 js compiler. It may be weaker than GWT's but maybe it suits your task better. Also, I think I remember that the RAP framework (part of eclipse foundation) will also compile at least parts of the code to javascript.

Comment: Is there a benefit to storing the JavaScript in the database rather than storing the Java (source code or class files) in the database?

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell Storing classes in a database table, the loading via a URL class loader might be possible, but if you want to reload another version of the classes w/o restarting the app server it seems to me like it would get complicated. If you have information to the contrary, please share.

Answer (score 1):

**Java and JavaScript are similar like Car and Carpet are similar.**

You will not found an universal solution, event one without bugs on complex code.

I, apologize but the best and the fastest solution is manually, step-by-step, because you will spent too much time on debug and on manual adjustment.